# how to deploy a mvc4+EntityFrame6 applicatin to iis?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I have a web application which uses mvc4+Entityframework 6. It works fine on local machine. However, when I create the website on the production iis, published all files, the site does not come up. It shows 500 error.

If I put a simple index.html file, rename the web.config to something else, the index.html shows up. It tells me the iis is working.

Do I need to install any runtime on production?

thanks

Comment: What is exactly the error?

Comment: Is connection string correct?

Comment: what is your iis version?

Answer (score 0):

it turns out that the machine is a new machine and nobody installed asp.net 4.5 on it. once installed it and mvc runtime (not sure this is must), it works fine.